# Play Store crashes when menu or back button are tapped

Tags: google-play-store, lg-optimus-l5

Since the Play Store was updated to version 4.9.13 on my LG Optimus L5II (LG-E450f), it crashes every time the menu or back button are tapped.

[image: Sorry! Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped]

<sup>Click image for larger version.</sup>

Everything else appears to work fine.

Clearing the cache, deleting app data and resetting to factory settings don't fix it. Uninstalling the updates of Play Store fixes it, but the after a couple of minutes it's automatically updated and the problem happens again.

My device isn't rooted. It's running Android version 4.1.2

What can I do to stop the Play Store crashing?

Comment: I just found a page about that offet to fix the problem by installing a apk file. [MOD-XPOSED-4.1.2+ - LG Optimus Jelly Bean Play Store Fix v1.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/lg-optimus-jelly-bean-play-store-fix-t2852146). I'm not sure if follow this is safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swipe from left edge to right don't fix the problem but make the menu accesible, and don't require to root the phone.

From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=55005591&postcount=2

> Swype from left edge to right or use XPosed module "x3 jelly bean play
>   store fix" if you've rooted your device

Answer (score 0):

If you root your phone then you can safely install [Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) and [this module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/lg-optimus-jelly-bean-play-store-fix-t2852146) that should fix the problem.

Comment: I need more details, like if there is a toolkit to solve soft brick / boot loops for my device.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on my phone, but luckily I found a way around it. Simply swipe in from the left hand side and it brings you the exact same menu you are after.

Comment: Swipe from the left only works if it's started from the edge.